# How should I handle errors inside or outside a Perl module?

Tags: perl, error-handling, perl-module

I started learning how to make a module in perl with [perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html):

```
 package Person;
 use strict;

 my($NAME, $AGE, $PEERS) = ( 0 .. 2 );

 sub new {
    my $self = [];
    $self->[$NAME] = undef;
    $self->[$AGE] = undef;
    $self->[$PEERS] = [];
    bless($self);
    return $self;
 }

 sub name {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { $self->[$NAME] = shift }
    return $self->[$NAME];
 }

 sub age {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { $self->[$AGE] = shift }
    return $self->[$AGE];
 }

 sub peers {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { @{ $self->[$PEERS] } = @_ }
    return @{ $self->[$PEERS] };
 }

 1;
```

- I would like to know how, if possible
  with sample code should I threat any
  errors within the module and outside
  it ?

For example:

```
 use Person;
 $test= Person->new() or die Person->Error;
```

or

```
sub new {
   my $self = [];
   $self->[$NAME] = undef;
   $self->[$AGE] = undef;
   $self->[$PEERS] = [];
   bless($self);
   #########
   # some error happened here and I need to say something
   #########
   return $self;
}
```

- If I call anything else within the
  module that had a error, problem,
  missing argument how is the correct
  way to tell there was an error ?

PS: Hope my question is not too off and hi everyone :)

Comment: You have written a lot of code to construct your objects and allow users to access and modify their attributes. You might want to have a look at [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) and similar modules to save yourself from quite some typing and possible sources of bugs.

Comment: @rafl - while a good idea for advanced user, knowing how to roll one's own module sans Moose is a must when learning Perl, which seems to be the stage the OP is at.

Comment: If you're going to use "classic" Perl OO rather than Moose (and I can see why that might be useful whilst learning Perl) then I highly recommend keeping it really classic by basing the object on a hash rather than an array.

Comment: @davorg the above module code is serving as an example only and it was copy and pasted from the tutorial listed just so i could show in a better way what i was talking about inside out error handling thinking that it would be more effective to get some example and suggestion from people but i belive it made the opposite effect hence so far i only got 1 answer to it.

Comment: That's pretty much my point. If you want generic advice then use cost that is as generic as possible. That is, use an example from the beginning of the tutorial, not from the section entitled "Alternate Object Representations". I'm sure I'm not the only person who wasted time trying to work out why you were using such non-standard code. Maybe that's why you got so few useful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) routines can be used to report errors.

```
use Carp qw{ croak };

sub new {
    my $self        = {};
    $self->{$NAME } = undef;
    $self->{$AGE  } = undef;
    $self->{$PEERS} = [];

    # replace the following with something appropriate
    if ($error_occurred) {
        croak 'Something did not work right';
    }

    return bless, $self;
}
```

Comment: Nice way of doing it, do you have a function to use that with too or you just wrap croak whenever you need to throw an expection at something ? i am really sorry that i can't upvote your answer yet as i dont have enough points but if someone reads this please upvote his answer.

Comment: Note that perl's exception mechanism is actually uses `die` to throw exceptions and `eval BLOCK` (or nice abstractions on top of that, such as [`Try::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny)) to catch them. `croak` is just sort of a wrapper around die. `perldoc -f die` has lots of more details on exceptions in perl.